# Classe que anteriormente já fez referência a um stackpane parece "perder" essa referência no futuro no JAVA

Tags: java, javafx

Salve, programadores!
Peço ajuda com um código de JavaFX do Java:
- eu tenho a classe controladora onde estão declarados todos os elementos gráficos com vários @FXML, inclusive uma variável stackPane. Eu passo esse stackPane como referência para a classe GUIboard quando eu a instâncio, de modo que dentro dessa última terei um "link" pro stackPane.
- Ainda dentro da GUIBoard, certa hora que quero carregar uma posição de xadrez no tabuleiro (especificado na string FENatual), eu chamo o método "drawBoard" abaixo (que está dentro da GUIBoard.java):

```java
public void drawBoard(String FENatual, StackPane stackPane2) { 
      drawEmptyBoard(stackPane2);
      refreshBoardImage(stackPane2, boardModel.getBoardASCII());
  }
```

O lance é que: se eu não passar a referência do stackPane no método da drawBoard a partir da minha classe controladora, ele não encontra o stackPane da classe GUIBoard que eu relacionei quando eu instanciei o objeto "boardGUI" também dentro da classe controladora:

```java
//Classe controladora:
public class ConstructChessBoard {
    private StackPane stackPane;

    public ConstructChessBoard() {
        boardGUI = new GUIboard(boardModel, stackPane);
    }
```

```java
public class GUIboard {
    private StackPane stackPane;
    public GUIboard(BoardModel boardModel, StackPane stackPane) { //Método construtor da GUIBoard
        this.stackPane = stackPane;
    }
```

A mensagem de erro é:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "javafx.scene.layout.StackPane.getChildren()" because "stackPane" is null
    at groupId/groupId.artifactId.view.GUIboard.drawEmptyBoard(GUIboard.java:278)
    at groupId/groupId.artifactId.view.GUIboard.drawBoard(GUIboard.java:552)
    at groupId/groupId.artifactId.controller.ConstructChessBoard.lambda$0(ConstructChessBoard.java:278)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:247)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.process(Scene.java:4098)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processKeyEvent(Scene.java:2157)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.keyEvent(Scene.java:2625)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:217)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:149)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleKeyEvent$1(GlassViewEventHandler.java:248)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:412)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleKeyEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:247)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleKeyEvent(View.java:547)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyKey(View.java:971)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$runLoop$11(GtkApplication.java:277)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

O erro da  se refere à:

```java
public void drawEmptyBoard(StackPane stackPane) {
    gridPane = new GridPane();
    stackPane.getChildren().add(gridPane); //O Erro .....drawEmptyBoard(GUIboard.java:278) é gerado nessa linha
}
```

Comment: Tente iniciar em modo debug e ver se alguma dessas variaveis ou algum dos parametros é `null`

Answer (score 0):

Seguindo a dica do Tiago Dinis chei o "erro"! : debugando e acompanhando a instanciação do objeto:

```
    public ConstructChessBoard() {
        boardGUI = new GUIboard(boardModel, stackPane); //É aqui que a classe 
//Controller do FXML instância um objeto a partir do qual eu chamo o método 
//drawBoard() que vai desenhar no meu stackPane
    }
```

verifiquei que quando a classe controller do FXML está executando seu método construtor ele ainda não tem de fato instâncias dos nodes/objetos que foram declarados no seu corpo (ou seja: apesar de eu ter declarado no corpo do ConstructChessBoard.java:
`@FXML private StackPane stackPane;` 
ele só tem uma instância desse objeto DEPOIS de executar sua classe construtora.
Utilizando o método:

```
    public void initialize() {
        boardGUI = new GUIboard(boardModel, stackPane);
    }
```

dentro da classe ConstructChessBoard permite que eu salve a referência do meu stackPane dentro da classe GUIboard, pois quando executa o initialize() ele já tem os objetos "montados realmente".

Obrigado mais uma vez Tiago Dinis!